# Type based on union type option

Tags: typescript

I would like to create an object where the property name is a value from a union type, and the type of the value based on that prop type, e.g:

```
type Direction =
  "horizontal"
  | "vertical"
  | "diagonal"
  ;

// Choose one of this types based on Direction option
interface HorizontalData { foo: number; }
interface VerticalData { bar: string; }
interface DiagonalData { baz: boolean; }

type Result<D extends Direction> = {
  data: << type based on D value >>;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You can define a type which represents the mapping from each property name to the corresponding `***Data`, like this:

```
type DirectionMapping = {
  "horizontal": HorizontalData
  "vertical": VerticalData
  "diagonal": DiagonalData
};
```

(Aside: If you want you can remove your original definition of `Direction` and replace it with:

```
type Direction = keyof DirectionMapping;
```

which amounts to the same thing, but keeps your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

Note that you will never need an *instance* of `DirectionMapping` at runtime.  Instead you use it to [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the output type in the definition of `Result`:

```
type Result<D extends Direction> = {
  data: DirectionMapping[D]; // uses indexed-access/lookup type 
};
```

And test that it behaves as expected:

```
const horz: Result<"horizontal"> = { data: { foo: 3 } }; // okay
const vert: Result<"vertical"> = { data: { foo: 3 } }; // error
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!